# minecraft forge - How would I get a entity and change it's state?

Tags: minecraft-forge

I'm starting out with forge modding and I want to make it so all creepers spawn as a charged creeper. I'm using forge MDK 1.16.3.

Here is my event handler:

```
package com.modder.mod.events;

import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;
import net.minecraftforge.event.entity.living.LivingSpawnEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.SubscribeEvent;

public class EventHandler 
{
    @SubscribeEvent
    public static void mobEvent(LivingSpawnEvent event)
    {
        Entity entity;
        
        
    }
}
```

But I do not know what to after this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LivingSpawnEvent` will fire every time an entity is spawned into a world, this includes when you leave and then return so keep that in mind.

As the event fires for every spawning entity, we want to check if the entity is a creeper and so we check that it's an instance of the `CreeperEntity` class and return if it's not.

```java
if(!(event.getEntity() instanceof CreeperEntity))
    return;
```

Now that we know we have a creeper, we can safely cast it to get the creeper entity. We then check if the creeper is already charged and return if so; as there's no need to continue.

```java
CreeperEntity creeper = (CreeperEntity) event.getEntity();
if(creeper.isCharged())
    return;
```

Normally, creepers are charged by a lightning strike and we can emulate this functionality to make the creeper charged:

```java
LightningBoltEntity lightningBoltEntity = new LightningBoltEntity(event.getWorld().getWorld(), event.getX(), event.getY(), event.getZ(), true);
((ServerWorld) event.getWorld()).addLightningBolt(lightningBoltEntity);
creeper.onStruckByLightning(lightningBoltEntity);
```

This strike will damage the creeper.

However, if we don't want a lightning strike, we have to change the `POWERED` data manager boolean. This field is private but we can use [reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html).

First, we define a new `Field` and then try and get the `POWERED` field and set it to accessible.

```java
Field field;
field = creeper.getClass().getDeclaredField("POWERED");
field.setAccessible(true);
```

We can then set the value to true which will set the creeper to charged.

```
DataParameter<Boolean> powered = (DataParameter<Boolean>) field.get(creeper);
creeper.getDataManager().set(powered, true);
```

Finally, we should wrap this in a try/catch because we don't control the content of `CreeperEntity` so we can't guarantee that our assumptions about its content will be accurate upon execution, so we define how we will deal with errors. In this case, I'm ignoring any expected exceptions for demonstration purposes.

```java
@SubscribeEvent
public void autoChargeCreeper(LivingSpawnEvent event)
{
    if(!(event.getEntity() instanceof CreeperEntity))
        return;
    CreeperEntity creeper = (CreeperEntity) event.getEntity();
    if(creeper.isCharged())
        return;
    try
    {
        Field field;
        field = creeper.getClass().getDeclaredField("POWERED");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        DataParameter<Boolean> powered = (DataParameter<Boolean>) field.get(creeper);
        creeper.getDataManager().set(powered, true);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException ignored) { }
}
```

Comment: Where is `Field` imported from

Comment: From `java.lang.reflect.Field`

Comment: Be careful when using reflection; this solution will break in production because it relies on a deobfuscated field name ('POWERED'). An easy solution is to use `ObfuscationReflectionHelper` and pass the SRG name of the field instead. You can find SRG names at [MCPBot](http://mcpbot.bspk.rs/). There are CSV tables mapping SRG names to deobfuscated names, and there is also an IRC bot that can provide more information on a member.